# Incorrect data appearing when joining a new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't understand what is happening here, I have one bit of code that works perfectly as expected. However once I modifiy it with another table I started getting extra data that in incorrect.

```
SELECT g.Name
     , b.roomNo 
     , b.From 
     , b.To 
     FROM Booking b
     JOIN Guest g ON g.No = b.gNo
     WHERE b.hNo = 1 AND b.From <= '10-01'
         AND (b.To IS NULL OR b.To >= '10-01');
```

I get this and all this information is correct, I have manually verified it.

```
NAME      ROOMNO FROM  TOO
--------- ------ ----- -----                                
Bob            5 09-27 10-04                                
Joe            4 09-21 10-24                                
Frank          7 09-30      
Peter          3 09-22 10-02
```

After I modify it to:

```
SELECT g.Name
     , b.roomNo
     , r.price   --<-- new
     , b.From
     , b.To 
     FROM Booking b
     JOIN Guest g ON g.No = b.gNo
     JOIN Room r ON r.roomNo = b.roomNo   --<-- new
     WHERE b.hNo = 1 AND b.From <= '10-01'
         AND (b.To IS NULL OR b.To >= '10-01');
```

This is what I get back.... Now I have checked and I know for a fact that each room only has one price, yet I am getting back two prices for each one. I can't understand this.

```
NAME      PRICE ROOMNO FROM  TOO
--------- ----- ------ ----- -----                                
Bob          55      5 09-27 10-04 -- <--correct price
Bob          60      5 09-27 10-04                                
Joe          55      4 09-21 10-24 -- <--correct price
Joe          60      4 09-21 10-24                                
Frank        90      7 09-30       -- <--correct price
Frank       100      7 09-30                                           
Peter        55      3 09-22 10-02 -- <--correct price
Peter        60      3 09-22 10-02
```

This might help too....

```
SELECT b.roomNo
 FROM Booking b
 WHERE b.hNo = 1;
```

Gives the correct 10 results:

```
ROOMNO                                                                      
------                                                                      
     7                                                                      
     5                                                                      
     5                                                                      
     5                                                                      
     1                                                                      
     3                                                                      
     4                                                                      
     7                                                                      
     2                                                                      
     3
```

However....

```
SELECT b.roomNo
    FROM Booking b
    JOIN Room r ON b.roomNo = r.roomNo
    WHERE b.hNo = 1;
```

Gives 80 results....

Comment: Duplicate room numbers in `Room` perhaps? Otherwise, could you add some sample data for all tables that shows the problem?

Comment: Nope I verified that too.. each room only appeared once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found my own answer after I don't want to know how many hours and it was far to simple.

```
JOIN Room r ON r.roomNo = b.roomNo AND b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
```

It was just that little add on to the code, since it didn't know the hotelNo field should be joined too.

```
SELECT g.Name
 , b.roomNo
 , r.price
 , b.From
 , b.To 
 FROM Booking b
 JOIN Guest g ON g.No = b.gNo
 JOIN Room r ON r.roomNo = b.roomNo AND b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo  --<-- new
 WHERE b.hNo = 1 AND b.From <= '10-01'
     AND (b.To IS NULL OR b.To >= '10-01');
```

Comment: Congratulations for solving your issue yourself. Please self-accept your own answer (click on the tick mark) in order to mark this question as "resolved". This is important for future visitors.